# How can I access elements of the array in the image using Angular 2+

Tags: arrays, angular, foreach

The code gets data from indexedDB using this.idb.retrieveData() method inside a service and assigns it to this.offline_texts array, my problem is that I can't iterate through the results, please check the attached image for console.log out put on this.offline_texts array. How can I iterate through this array

```
this.offline_texts.push(this.idb.retrieveData() || []);
 this.offline_texts.forEach((messages) => {
      if (messages.status == '0') {
         this.messageService.sendMessage(messages)
          .subscribe(
             data => {
               this.messagesAll();
               this.status = 'true';
            },err =>{
               console.log("Error " +err)
             });
       }
    });
```

console.log(this.offline_texts) outputs the results on the below picture.

[Results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CA3X.png)

Comment: You have an array within an array. And so in your code above `messages` is also an array, and won't have a `status` property. Is the problem not with the first line, where you're pushing into `offline_texts`, instead of assigning to it?

Comment: Thanks for the input but how can I loop through the array as it is?

Comment: Well, you either have to iterate both the outer and inner arrays, or assume that there is at least one item.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array within an array. And so in your code above `messages` is also an array, and won't have a status property.

I think the problem is with the first line, where you're pushing into `offline_texts`, which should probably be:

```js
this.offline_texts = this.idb.retrieveData() || [];
```

But if you're keeping `offline_texts` as an array, you need to iterate both:

```js
this.offline_texts.push(this.idb.retrieveData() || []);
// First loop the arrays within offline_text
for (const messages of this.offline_texts) {
    // Each item is an array of messages, so we loop once more
    for (const message of messages) {
        if (message.status == '0') {
            this.messageService.sendMessage(message)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.messagesAll();
                    this.status = 'true';
                }, err => {
                    console.log("Error " + err)
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cobus, once again thanks for your input. I have changed this.offline_texts.push(this.idb.retrieveData() || []); to this.offline_texts = this.idb.retrieveData() || []; and I get one array but the foreach is not executing